# How to use order by case with an alias column on Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

This works, i can order with my alias_column

```sql
SELECT my_column AS alias_column FROM my_table ORDER BY alias_column ASC
```

But when i try to use my alias column in the ORDER BY with CASE, it doesn't work (alias_column does not exist)

```sql
SELECT my_column AS alias_column FROM my_table 
ORDER BY CASE alias_column 
WHEN 1 THEN 1 
WHEN 2 THEN 2 
END ASC
```

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a derived table:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT my_column AS alias_column 
  FROM my_table
) t
ORDER BY CASE alias_column 
                WHEN 1 THEN 1 
                WHEN 2 THEN 2 
              END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The alias name doesn't actually exist during the execution of the component creates it. That is why the solution offered by @a_horse_with_no_name works, he references the alias only after the sub-select has completed. During the execution where an alias is created you must use the name that is being aliased.

```
select my_column as alias_column 
  from my_table 
 order by case my_column 
               when 1 then 1 
               when 2 then 2 
          end asc;
```